# error in after lanching emulator

Tags: android-emulator

I successfully launched an emulator, but after displaying vitual device in system the following errors are occuring:

```
Renderer error: failed to create/resize pbuffer!!
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x505
draw: Could not use program error=0x501
draw: Could not glDrawElements() error=0x505
Failed to alloc 16777216 bytes for ReadBuffer
```

Suddenly, loading of virtual device stops. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I had same errors from two days, This is how I solved this issue

1. downloaded the appropriate system image(64 / 86  system)
2. allocated less memory(in my case it was 700mb) in avd manager while creating new device(my system has 4gb ram)
3. restarted emulator